# How come this c# code is not working

Tags: c#

How come this c# code is not working.

```
Console.Write("What is your awesomeness level: ");
int Level = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int Isaac_Level = Level + (100 * Level);
var remainder = Isaac_Level - Level;
if (Isaac_Level > Level)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Isaac's Awesome Level is higher than yours by ", remainder);
}
```

Something is wrong with the remainder - it doesn't appear in the output from the Console.WriteLine.

I have tried a lot, please tell me what is wrong.

Comment: What is the error? Or what is the input and expected output?

Comment: `{0}` is missing in `Console.WriteLine` string

Comment: it should be `Console.WriteLine("Isaac's Awesome Level is higher than yours by {0}", remainder);`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to improve formatting. I also tried to clarify your problem statement to increase the chances of people being able to understand what you need. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error here:

```
Console.WriteLine("Isaac's Awesome Level is higher than yours by ", remainder);
```

instead use this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Isaac's Awesome Level is higher than yours by " + remainder);
```

or with C# 6 feature:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Isaac's Awesome Level is higher than yours by {remainder}");
```

also, use a try catch statement to convert and `Console.ReadLine();` when you want user to read something